# How we can give the floating in one paragraph

Tags: jasper-reports

How we can use the static text in the between of two parameter

http://prntscr.com/drovgu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the parameter with the static text like below,

```
$P{Parameter1}+" This is the static text between parameter1 and parameter2. "+$P{Parameter2}+". This is another static text after parameter2."
```

Use the above kind of structure in the expression of jasper report `text field` component.

Comment: how we can add this $P{Parameter1}+" in paramenter ?

Comment: i want to make like this http://prntscr.com/drqdt5 but there should be no limit in parameter content .

Comment: You have the `management-report-title` parameter in a text field right? Double click the text field in your design. You will see the expression window. There you have to modify like `$P{management-report-title}+" Foretaget har sitt sate i "+$P{resident}`

Comment: You have **three different text fields in your design**. Remove all those three components. Then add only **one text field** from palette and double click the text filed. Expression window will pop-up, in the **text expression** provide the expression which I have given in above comment and try running the report. **No need of three separate fields for this**.

Comment: Thanks a lot man i appreciate your response this is perfectly working for me how ever i was looking i also added float and strech overflow

Comment: In the table component , when I am trying to use Field in printWhenExpression , it is giving me the error field not found . I have to remove the column if there is no value under that column.  I tried to use the parameter as well as variable in printWhenExpression but the same error . @viki888

Comment: @Bhupinderkumar I cannot get you. If your problem is not related to this question, kindly create a new question. Thank you.

Comment: its a new problem

Comment: @Bhupinderkumar If so, please create a new question which details your problem.

Comment: @Bhupinderkumar May I know why this answer has been removed from best answer?